# How to Make an Object Able to be Screwed In/Out With a Sideways Knob

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I am trying to make a device that can go up or down a screw by twisting a knob, kind of like a wing nut, but the wing would be sideways (I suppose). To clarify what I mean by this, please see a simplified version in a diagram below.

[image]

I think this type of engineering has already been used in various devices, such as a microscope, where the course adjustment knob will raise or lower the "stage" of the microscope.

Does anyone know where a part/device like this could be found, or how I would go about making something similar?

Thank you so much for your time and kindness,

Kelsey Nealon

Comment: See "worm gear".

Comment: Or more likely "rack and pinion".

Comment: Conventional screw threads are not designed to be meshed with pinion type gears.  Ideally you'd want a custom screw thread (on the vertical axis in your picture) with an involute gear tooth pattern as the thread profile.  However this would not necessarily "stay put" after you let go of the knob (insert double-entendre here), so you'd still need some sort of locking mechanism.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I can't see a worm gear working in this instance as it would be trying to reverse drive the worm - there is too much friction to achieve this. A rack and pinion would not stay in place after releasing the knob.

You could use a 90 degree bevel gear with an internal thread in the output gear like the one in the photo.

[image]